# Как вставить php код?

Tags: smarty

CMS использует Smart. Как инклюдить php код на страницу?

Answer (score 1):

```
{include_php file='/somepath/somefile.php'}
```

или

```
{php}
include ("somepath/somefile.php");
{/php}
```

Comment: вот что выдает
вставил в шаблоне {php} <?php include("left.php")?> {/php}
выводит - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '
<' in ......... hosting.ru/public_html/Smarty/libs/plugins/block.php.php(23) : eval()'d code on line 1<br />

Comment: не

    {php} <?php include("left.php")?> {/php}

а

    {php} include("left.php"); {/php}

Comment: не получается

здесь http://tur.guru-hosting.ru/  в левой колонке под словом Валюта!!!

Comment: лишнее в коде что-то...
скинь куда нить код...

Comment: <!-- Выбор валюты -->
   {* Выбор валюты только если их больше одной *}
   {if $currencies|count>1}
   <div id="currencies">
    <h2>Валюта!!!</h2>
    {php} include("left.php"); {/php}
   </div> 
   {/if}
   <!-- Выбор валюты (The End) -->

Answer (score 0):

показываю вариант для InstantCMS 1.10.3
Особенность - там используется специальная папка в корень которой кидают самописные php файлы. Папка "includes" файл любой какой придумаете, в моём случае:

```
/includes/pathway.php
```

код для вставки (инклудирования) php кода находящегося в данном файле:

```
{php} cmsPage::getInstance()->printPathway(); {/php}
```